# Make a fields Many2many depend on another fields Many2one in odoo

Tags: xml, odoo-8

I am new in Odoo and i have two fields

```
gathering_id = fields.Many2one('health_administrator.gathering_model')
key_letter_id = fields.Many2many('health_administrator.key_letter')
```

The fields key_letter_id depend on fields gathering_id
ex: when i make a selection on gathering_id, the fields is loaded depend on the selection in the fields gathering_id .

How i can do that

Thanks.

Comment: The field key_letter_id is a Many2one not Many2many

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Onchange many2one filed in odoo

Today you will learn how to create a dependent drop down (many2one) fields in Odoo. For example I have two many2one fields (campus_id and department_id), and we want to change the department on the basis of campus field.

campus_id = fields.Many2one('model.campus', string="Campus Name")
department_id = fields.Many2one('model.department', string="Department Name")

```
1    @api.onchange('campus_id')
2    def _campus_onchange(self):
3        res = {}
4        res['domain']={'department_id':[('campus_id', '=', self.campus_id.id)]}
5        return res
```

Code Description:
In line no 1 we use @api.onchange decorator for campus_id. It means whenever campus changes or select a campus from many2one filed do the following line of code (3,4,5).  In line no 3 we declare a dict named res. In line no 4 we use domain to change the department field.

Source : [Learn Programming Onchange many2one filed in odoo](http://learnopenerp.blogspot.com/2016/10/onchange-many2one-filed-in-odoo.html)